# Translate a rectangle in canvas

Tags: html, recursion, html5-canvas, rectangles

I am unable to clear a rectangle completely using `clearRect` method which is being translated on canvas across `X` direction. The problem can be seen live at [JS Bin - Link to demo](http://jsbin.com/anacok/1/edit)

**JS code**

```
(function() {  

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.fillStyle = '#ccc';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50); //x,y,w,h

  translate(canvas, context, 0, 0, 100, 50, 'x', 5);

  function translate(canvas, context, x, y, w, h, direction, interval) {
    context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

    if (direction == 'x') {
      if ((x + interval + w >= canvas.width) || (x + interval < 0)) interval = -1 * interval;

      setTimeout(function() {
        context.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
        translate(canvas, context, x + interval, y, w, h, direction, interval);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

}());
```

It is leaving traces before moving forward/backward. And I have used the same dimensions to clear the rectangle which were used to draw it.

Please observe the complete path for observing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 and FF21 work fine, Chrome gives the "remnants".

Even then, I can't consistently reproduce the misbehaving effect.

Also notice that when you scroll your jsbin results panel the remnants go away. So Chrome becomes aware that these remnant pixels shouldn't be there.

Looks like yet another canvas bug in Chrome (possibly, but not necessarily, related to anti-aliasing).

You could hack at it by extending your clear area to erase the remnants.  Alternatively you could leave out the translate and increment x by interval to move your rect.

Hacky fix:

```
context.clearRect(x+((interval>0)?-.5:.5), y, w, h);
```

Comment: You are right. Works fine in Firefox 21.0 and thanks for the fix.